# Is there a built-in checksum utility on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hashing, checksum

Is there a built-in checksum/hash utility on Windows 7?

Comment: Not my area, but Powershell, the build in scripting language, can probably do it.

Comment: Is this one of those goofy "I'm not allowed to install *any* 3rd party software" requirements?  If so, try googling for "PowerShell SHA1 hash" and you should get some scripts/cmdlets that will run on the built-in PowerShell using MS's Crypto APIs.

Comment: I am positive I once installed a windows-explorer sfv checker that displayed overlay green check arrows icons, (like tortoise svn do) when it checked a match against a .sfv file named the same than the checked file. however can't find it anymore.

Comment: There is GetFile-Hash. You need PS 4.0 or community extensions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521061/how-to-get-an-md5-checksum-in-powershell

Comment: Avast anti virus is blocking downloads from the above site for me, so may be worth approaching with caution.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/889768

Comment: Note, the best answer (for me) is the 2nd answer, which has many more votes than the answer chosen by the asker.
To the reader: look below, for the "certutil.exe" option.

Comment: @afrazier I'm coming to this a lot later but the reason why someone might be looking for a built in hash is that if Windows has already calculated one as part of the file system housekeeping then I can check if 2 files are identical without reading all the data.

Answer (score 234, accepted):

There is a built in utility, as specified in [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/898377).

You may, however, wish to use this freeware app called [HashTab](http://implbits.com/products/hashtab/) that integrates neatly with Windows Explorer by registering a... well, a tab in the properties dialog of files. It's pretty sweet.

[image: HashTab screenshot]

Comment: I prefer [HashCheck](http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/) over HashTab, primarily because it can handle multiple mixed file/folder selections and it can create/verify SFV/MD5/SHA1 files.  [My writeup](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=33861&p=891309#p891309) over at the Ars Forums goes into more detail.

Comment: Be aware HashTab is only free for private use! HashCheck is open source and complete free (BSD license)

Comment: Also HashCheck is 85kB, awesome.

Comment: HashTab and HashCheck are great tools. Too bad that neither supports SHA-256.

Comment: @JustinY HashTab supports SHA-256 since version 4 if I remember well. Just click the 'Settings' option above the Hash Comparison text field :)

Comment: yes, there is a cmd: CertUtil -hashfile _main.exe MD5

Comment: I'll also note that HashCheck raises alerts with Norton Anti-Virus

Comment: Thanks, and yes, HashTab seems to be providing more functionalities, such as larger array of hashes ... but, man, **I hate** download sites that require you to provide your email to get a link! You know that an avalanche of spam is right then on its way...

Comment: No folder / DVD hashing capability in HashTab!

Comment: A maintained version of [HashCheck](https://github.com/gurnec/HashCheck) also supports SHA-256 and even SHA-512.

Comment: FYI, hash algorithm string is case sensitive. Don't headdesk.

Comment: "There is a built-in utility which does exactly what you need. You may, however, use this other tool which does something which you didn't ask for." Why is this the accepted answer?

Comment: > "Thanks. Unfortunately being built-in was an essential requirement for me."
Then why did you select a non-built in software, which the question doesn't ask for, as the answer?

Comment: i've used it in the past and the user experience is nice -- but if i can't download over https (secured by a trusted cert) then what's the point?

Comment: I love the way HashTab works. Unfortunately, it doesn't support SHA256 which I need for my Kubuntu image.

Comment: This and other tools produce pretty much the same result, just mind the uppercase especially if you're comparing hashes on code.

Comment: @Vince You can make it show SHA256 by right-clicking on the list of hashes and selecting "Settings".

Comment: The Hastab link in the answer today goes to a website which says "HashTab was discontinued in early 2022."  So I guess it is dead. There are other good alternatives listed in other answers.

Answer (score 1375):

[**CertUtil**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil) is a pre-installed Windows utility that can be used to generate hash checksums:

```
certUtil -hashfile pathToFileToCheck [HashAlgorithm]
```

HashAlgorithm choices: MD2 MD4 MD5 SHA1 SHA256 SHA384 SHA512

So for example, the following generates an MD5 checksum for the file 
`C:\TEMP\MyDataFile.img`:

```
  CertUtil -hashfile C:\TEMP\MyDataFile.img MD5
```

To get output similar to *Nix systems you can add some PowerShell magic:

```
$(CertUtil -hashfile C:\TEMP\MyDataFile.img MD5)[1] -replace " ",""
```

Comment: MD5.bat:

@certutil -hashfile %1 MD5|find /v "hash of file"|find /v "CertUtil"

Comment: Please note that `certutil` is **not available in Windows PE**, so if you are trying to calculate a checksum in a pre-deployment task script in PE, you will have to use an external tool like **Microsoft FCIV**.

Comment: That's incredible, but `CertUtil -hashfile C:\TEMP\MyDataFile.img MD5` does not produce the same hash than `md5sum /tmp/MyDataFile.img` under Linux (I guarranty it is the same file with a mount)

Comment: `certutil` produces the same hash that the "GNU on Windows" version of `md5sum` does.

Comment: @lalebarde There is only one standard for MD5. If you are getting different results on the same file, it is because something is making some change to that file and causing the hashes to be different. This is one of the most important functions of MD5 and other hashing standards.

Comment: Which versions of Windows is it included with by default?

Comment: It seems that in older versions of Windows, CertUtil may exist, but `-hashfile` may not support different hash algorithms, producing only a SHA-1 sum.

Comment: Where can I find the list of available hash-algorithms? I tried `certutil -hashfile -?` but did not get the list of options. The [website](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732443(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_hashfile) does not have it as well.

Comment: From the edit logs, this answer was replicated from [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478722/what-is-the-best-way-to-calculate-a-checksum-for-a-file-that-is-on-my-machine).

Comment: When using certutil I'm gettin a different MD5 and SH1 hash than what is expected when downloaded tomcat:
it generates this:
fd fe 6d 02 b5 4c d1 c2 11 4a 8b 31 38 52 a0 96

http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.6/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.6.zip

7dfefe03154b5c852d5163d60a179e3d *apache-tomcat-8.5.6.zip

Why the difference?  I don't think it's a MIM attack (Man in The Middle)

Comment: @mwfearnley, it looks like `SHA1` is the default when the hash algorithm parameter is left unspecified, and that, when specified, the hash algorithm parameter is case-sensitive.  So, I first tried `certutil -hashfile ... sha1` and it failed.  Then I left the `...sha1` off, and it worked.  Then I retried with `...SHA1` and that worked.  (And I repeated the test for md5/MD5.)

Comment: Strangely, I get error 0xd0000225 for non-existent algorithms (e.g. `MD3`), but 0xd00000bb if the algorithm exists but the case is wrong (e.g. `md5`, `sHa1`)

Comment: It's also worth noting that if FIPS 140 certified algorithms are required on the system by Local Security Policy or Group Policy, the older algorithms and/or libraries that haven't gone through FIPS certification will produce an error if attempted to be used (e.g. MD5)

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer? The question specifically asks for a built-in utility

Comment: @pbarney I think you mean `findstr` rather than `find`? This batch file outputs just the bare hash for me... 
`@certutil -hashfile %1 MD5|findstr /v "hash of file"|findstr /v "CertUtil"`

Comment: CertUtil is great, but without this post I could not do a SHA256 checksum. Unlike other DOS commands, /? does NOT give full usage info. Also, the commands are CASE sensitive. Keyword sha256 does not work

Comment: I had to set the protocol to sha256 to match

Answer (score 201):

I'm using [HashCheck](http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/) ([latest version](https://github.com/gurnec/HashCheck/releases)) which integrates itself as a property page for files and includes a context menu to compare against hash check files (SFV).

It is free, and the source is available.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: this one is very nice , i tested it on 1GB file and its faster then Summer Properties.

Comment: Hilarious app. Definitely the best. It can check the hash with a doubleclick on the created file.MD5! And it remembers what files were hashed.

Comment: AVG is flagging `REGSVR32.EXE` as a virus threat after installation

Comment: @MikePennington: In other words, AVG is flagging a core Windows utility as malicious. Nice!

Comment: AVG is flagging that the core Windows Utility has been changed - that is the sort of thing that malicious software often does.

Comment: Free, open source, integrates with property page and explorer context menu, has an .MD5 checker and supports SHA-1. Not to mention it's just 85kb and runs _really_ fast. This application is **absurdly great**, thank you!

Comment: and you can install it via chocolatey!

Comment: @Sossenbinder You must have been looking in the wrong place. SHA-256 has been supported since Dec. '14. The tool was being updated until at least Sep '16 so while it may not be active lately perhaps there's not much to add to it. https://github.com/gurnec/HashCheck/releases

Comment: i've used it in the past and the user experience is nice -- but if i can't download over https (secured by a trusted cert) then what's the point?

Comment: Note that HashCheck doesn't do SHA256. 7-Zip is an easier solution if you need this.

Comment: I know this is really old, but how did you answer the question more than a year before it was asked?

Comment: @AndrewMoore Both links you provided lead to different installers (HashCheckSetup-2.4 and HashCheckInstall-2.1), are they the same?

Comment: If someone is looking for a maintained alternative, see **[OpenHashTab](https://superuser.com/a/1710347/89979)**.

Comment: HashCheck doesn't handle long paths properly (> MAX_PATH i.e. 260 symbols).

Answer (score 97):

PowerShell version 4 and up includes the [Get-FileHash](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn520872.aspx) cmdlet.

```
powershell get-filehash -algorithm md5 <file_to_check>
```

Use [doskey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003/tool-for-commandline-bookmarks-on-windows) to make a persistent alias that's easier to remember.

```
doskey sha1sum=powershell get-filehash -algorithm sha1 "$1"
doskey md5sum=powershell get-filehash -algorithm md5 "$1"
```

Comment: By adding Format-List to show the full output if the hash result string is too long     `powershell Get-FileHash -Algorithm md5 <file_to_check> | Format-List`

Comment: Finally it comes to PowerShell!

Comment: Brilliant question and answers. Thanks for all of this. I'd recommend another software, but this is pretty complete. Can't thank you contributors enough for this thread.

Excuse me... May I ask why PowerShell on Win 8.1 and 10 won't recognize `Get-FileHash "C:\foo.exe" -Algorithm MD5,SHA1,SHA256 | Format-List` natively to list several hashes in a row? There's no such instruction stored in the console? I tried to reformulate several times with the correct syntax, but it returns me an error and it doesn't seem to work without embedding a script.

Comment: This needs more attention as this is built-in unlike many of the other options including the accepted answer.

Answer (score 87):

There is the FCIV utility from Microsoft, the [Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841290/availability-and-description-of-the-file-checksum-integrity-verifier-u)
 ([download link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/f/4/cf454ae0-a4bb-4123-8333-a1b6737712f7/Windows-KB841290-x86-ENU.exe)).

> The Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier tool is an unsupported command line utility that computes MD5 or SHA1 cryptographic hashes for files.

It doesn't show Windows 7 in system requirements but I've just used it in Windows 8 and it worked.

Comment: Why are we linking to a unsupported command line utility.  This doesn't even intergrate into the shell which I am sure the author wanted.

Comment: That utility was useful for me. I downloaded an iso image from msdn and needed to cheksum it. I didn't want any third party tools. I didn't need the shell integration and the author didn't ask for it. It's from a trusted source Microsoft and while unsupported it still works. I posted a link here because other people like me may find it useful.

Comment: I'm with @creator.  It may not be supported software, but at least Microsoft is the author.  Checksum programs are potentially really important to maintaining security; I'd rather not get mine from some random third-party.

Comment: While it's an OKish utility for moderate use, it's unstable. I'm using it in a xdelta script to determine if files of same size are different and I'm sorry to say I get about 1 crash every a few hundred files. It's unreliable, so an advice: use something else.

Comment: [PsFCIV](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-File-Checksum-e57dcd67) is PowerShell rewrite that supports the original's XML database functionality plus SHA-256, SHA-384 and, and SHA-512 hashes.

Comment: FCIV hasn't been installed on any Windows system I've wanted to use it on, but certUtil was always there. I wish FCIV wasn't a top search result when I forget the name of the tool to use. I also wish this feature was just built in to the file properties dialog and browser download managers.

Answer (score 51):

The new version of [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) also gives you the option of checksums just by right clicking (this doesn't include [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)). It has [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1), [SHA-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), CRC-32, CRC-64, etc.

[image].

For MD5 you can download [HashTab](http://implbits.com/products/hashtab/) and check by right clicking and then properties.

[image]

Comment: Which version of 7-zip are you talking about?

Comment: Unfortunately, the 7-zip checksum tool doesn't allow you to copy the checksum!

Comment: I think selecting the hash text and Ctrl+C works fine.

Comment: In my setup, if you go to properties of the file, you can copy the hash via right click->copy under file hashes tab.

Answer (score 24):

Here's one I've used before that integrates nicely with Explorer's "Properties" dialog: [Summer Properties](http://www.frozenlogic.org/summerproperties.shtml).  It's **open source**, and an **x64 version is also available**.

[image: SummerProperties screen shot]

I also like Safer Networking's [FileAlyzer](http://www.safer-networking.org/en/filealyzer/index.html), which provides additional features as well.  But just for checksums, Summer Properties is lightweight and does the job.

Comment: The only problem with this is that it does not support folders or groups of files. It is also out of dvlp

Comment: Another problem with it is that you can't paste an hash into it and see if it matches

Comment: I know this is really old, but how did you answer the question more than a year before it was asked?

Comment: @Baruch If you look at the [question's edit history](https://superuser.com/posts/245775/revisions) you'll see that, in May 2015, another similar question (but older) had its answers merged into this one. I'm not sure why the newer question was the one chosen to survive, but that's why it looks odd. Here's the [original older question](https://superuser.com/questions/89191/looking-for-md5-utility-that-integrates-to-windows).

Answer (score 16):

Nirsoft's **[HashMyFiles](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/hash_my_files.html)** is small utility that allows you to calculate the MD5 and SHA1 hashes of one or more files in your system. You can easily copy the MD5/SHA1 hashes list into the clipboard, or save them into text/html/xml file.

> HashMyFiles can also be launched from
>   the context menu of Windows Explorer,
>   and display the MD5/SHA1 hashes of the
>   selected file or folder.

[image]

*HashMyFiles is freeware and portable.*

Comment: +1, Seems like a new one -- the last time I checked (before moving to a command line **md5sum** version) was FastSum -- but, it was sort-of trialware and nagged a lot. **HashMyFiles** is good because it allows drag-and-drop of multiple files and export to CSV (both important features). Don't think I had seen it when I found FastSum a couple of years back.

Comment: that's right, HashMyFiles is a fairly recent addition to NirSoft's portfolio, it was first released in 2007.

Comment: *`…that integrates into Windows [Explorer]`*

Comment: And very small size!

Answer (score 16):

I am adding this here only because I didn't see any fully working powershell examples, ready for copy-paste:

```
C:\> powershell "Get-FileHash %systemroot%\system32\csrss.exe"

Algorithm       Hash
---------       ----
SHA256          CB41E9D0E8107AA9337DBD1C56F22461131AD0952A2472B4477E2649D16E...

C:\> powershell -c "(Get-FileHash -a MD5 '%systemroot%\system32\csrss.exe').Hash"

B2D3F07F5E8A13AF988A8B3C0A800880

C:\> CertUtil -hashfile "%systemroot%\system32\csrss.exe" MD5 | findstr -v file
b2 d3 f0 7f 5e 8a 13 af 98 8a 8b 3c 0a 80 08 80

C:\>
```

### 2019 Update:

The `certutil` output seems to have changed since Windows 8, so my old filter to isolate the hash doesn't work anymore. The extraneous spaces are gone too - one less thing to worry about when scripting. Here is the new copy-paste-able demo:

```
C:\>CertUtil -hashfile "%systemroot%\system32\csrss.exe" | findstr -v ash
0300c7833bfba831b67f9291097655cb162263fd

C:\>CertUtil -hashfile  "%systemroot%\system32\csrss.exe" SHA256 | findstr -v :
a37d616f86ae31c189a05b695571732073b9df97bf5a5c7a8ba73977ead3e65b

C:\>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.1451]

C:\>
```

To make this more resilient against breakage from yet another future change in `certutil`, we should look for lines with non-hex characters to filter out: `[^0-9a-zA-Z]`. That should also make it safer for other locales and languages.

```
C:\>CertUtil -hashfile  "C:\windows\fonts\arial.ttf" | findstr -vrc:"[^0123-9aAb-Cd-EfF ]"
12c542ef8c99cf3895ad069d31843a5210857fdc
```

Why is that actual anti-hex regex so weird ? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635740/why-does-findstr-not-handle-case-properly-in-some-circumstances) to learn how regex ranges in `findstr` don't work as they should. I included an extra space character for backward-compatibility with older `certutil` versions, but it is optional.

Note that the powershell `Get-FileHash` default is SHA256, while `certutil` still defaults to SHA1. So specify your algorithm explicitly where needed. You can quickly check the available options like this:

```
C:\>powershell -c "Get-FileHash -?" | findstr gori

    Get-FileHash [-Path] <string[]> [-Algorithm {SHA1 | SHA256 | SHA384 | SHA512 | MACTripleDES | MD5 | RIPEMD160}]
    Get-FileHash -LiteralPath <string[]> [-Algorithm {SHA1 | SHA256 | SHA384 | SHA512 | MACTripleDES | MD5 |
    Get-FileHash -InputStream <Stream> [-Algorithm {SHA1 | SHA256 | SHA384 | SHA512 | MACTripleDES | MD5 | RIPEMD160}]

C:\>certutil -hashfile -v /? | findstr gori

  CertUtil [Options] -hashfile InFile [HashAlgorithm]
Hash algorithms: MD2 MD4 MD5 SHA1 SHA256 SHA384 SHA512
```

Answer (score 14):

I found this PowerShell script:

```
param([switch]$csv, [switch]$recurse)

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Security") | out-null
$sha1 = new-Object System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed
$pathLength = (get-location).Path.Length + 1

$args | %{
    if ($recurse) {
        $files = get-childitem -recurse -include $_
    }
    else {
        $files = get-childitem -include $_
    }

    if ($files.Count -gt 0) {
        $files | %{
            $filename = $_.FullName
            $filenameDisplay = $filename.Substring($pathLength)

            if ($csv) {
                write-host -NoNewLine ($filenameDisplay + ",")
            } else {
                write-host $filenameDisplay
            }

            $file = [System.IO.File]::Open($filename, "open", "read")
            $sha1.ComputeHash($file) | %{
                write-host -NoNewLine $_.ToString("x2")
            }
            $file.Dispose()

            write-host
            if ($csv -eq $false) {
                write-host
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Source: [Calculating SHA1 in PowerShell](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/03/calculating-sha1-in-powershell.html)

It leverages .NET which I assume you have installed

Comment: Win 7 comes with .NET 3.5 and PowerShell v2, and PowerShell has always been dependent on .NET, so if you've got PS, you've got .NET.  :-)

Answer (score 8):

*[Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier](http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/f/4/cf454ae0-a4bb-4123-8333-a1b6737712f7/Windows-KB841290-x86-ENU.exe)*. It can compute [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) and [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash values.

Download, extract the files, then open a command prompt, go to the extracted path and then type the following command:

```
fciv -md5 filepath\filename.extension
```

For example:

```
fciv -md5 d:\programs\setup.exe
```

Comment: This answer and @creator's answer should be combined. They refer to the same tool.

Comment: Question Title : Is there a **built-in** checksum/hash utility on Windows 7? `'fciv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]

Answer (score 8):

A batch file based on pbarney's comment to the answer with the most upvotes: This copies the MD5 hash of whatever file is dragged onto the batch file to the clipboard:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i IN ('@certutil -hashfile %1 MD5 ^| find /v "hash of file" ^| find /v "CertUtil"') DO SET r=%%i
SET r=%r: =%
ECHO %r% | clip
```

To make it a context menu item instead:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Get MD5]
@="Copy MD5 to Clipboard"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Get MD5\command]
@="\"C:\\<PATH TO BAT FILE>\\getMD5.bat\" \"%1\""
```

Comment: Or if you don't mind the extra output, a one liner batch file `certutil -hashfile %1 md5` works as well

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, not that I'm aware of, but Microsoft's [Sysinternals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winternals) suite includes a nice tool called **[sigcheck](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb897441)**.

Answer (score 4):

[MD5 Context Menu](http://www.vonwangelin.com/md5/) does exactly this. It adds an **[MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)** option to the context menu of files:

[image]

[image]

MD5 Context Menu is a freeware shell extension for Windows which displays the MD5 hash sum of the selected file.

It says it's compatible with Windows 95, 98, ME, NT, 2000, and XP, although it works for me perfectly fine on Windows 7. It's a tiny download (238 KB) and includes everything you need.

Comment: "Because of a serious bug in the last version of our tool for large files with sizes > 2^31 bytes (~2.1GB) we currently do not provide the download anymore."

Answer (score 4):

[Cygwin](http://cygwin.org) contains an `md5sum.exe` utility that should do what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately being command line based, it doesn't integrate with the Windows Shell.

Comment: Cristian Ciupitu just cause you don't know how to do it it doesn't mean it can't be done. I'm using lots of CLI apps from Windows Shell desktop / folder background and typed apps context menu and they work fine.

Comment: Cygwin is massively overkill. There are many native binaries that do the job,  most of them under 200k.

Comment: There is nothing "massively overkill" about Cygwin.  The setup utility lets you check off and download only just exactly what you need and nothing more.  If all you select is md5sum, that's all you get.

Answer (score 4):

[QuickHash](http://sourceforge.net/projects/quickhash/) supports SHA-256 and SHA-512. I needed SHA-256 support to verify the checksum of whitelisted JavaScript libraries for inclusion in a Firefox addon.

Comment: Updated link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/quickhash/?source=directory (side note: [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/) currently uses SHA-256 for their checksums too.)

Comment: Thanks, this was the easiest and the fastest.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a cmd shell script which uses [tedr2's answer](https://superuser.com/a/898377/178806) but strips off the extraneous output lines and spaces:

```
:: hash.cmd : Get a hash of a file
:: p1: file to be hashed
:: p2: Hash algorithm in UPPERCASE
:: p3: Output file

@setlocal
@for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (
'@certutil -hashfile %1 %2 ^|find /v "hash of file" ^|find /v "CertUtil"'
) do @(
  @set str=%%a
)
@set str=%str: =%
@echo %str%
@endlocal
```

The output can be re-directed to a file if required:

```
@echo %str% > %3
```

e.g.

```
sys> \dev\cmd\hash.cmd MyApp.dll SHA1
8ae6ac1e90ccee52cee5c8bf5c2445d6a92c0d4f
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is of course, yes, CertUtil (see [tedr2's answer](https://superuser.com/a/898377/125659)).

But I'll add Penteract's free [File Checksum Verifier](https://penteract.net/site/Site/Apps/Developers/FileChecksumVerifier/FileChecksumVerifier.aspx)  which, I think, is one of the most user-friendly programs. (Disclaimer: I'm affiliated with Penteract.)

Some of its advantages:

- Compares the calculated and expected hashes for you.
- Minimalistic - no item in files' context-menus, no extra tab on
  files' properties.

To verify this program's integrity (against [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)) - it downloads over a secure connection.

[image: Penteract File Checksum Verifier]

Plus: free, offline (so you don't have to upload your files), user-friendly (drag a file in and get the result), launches from the start menu (no need to look for the downloaded executable when you want to use it a year from now), and supports MD5, SHA1, SHA256, etc.

Comment: Thank you for disclosing your affiliation. However, please avoid making too many posts of this kind, as doing so may be considered spamming. For more information about promotional posts, please see http://superuser.com/help/promotion.

Comment: This only works on Windows 10 and the op specifically asked about W7.

Comment: Worked fine for me on Windows 10. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. checksum

I use [**checksum**](https://chocolatey.org/packages/checksum) command-line utility.

- [**Open source**](https://github.com/ferventcoder/checksum),
- Support `md5`, `sha1`, `sha256` and `sha512`.

Usage:

> checksum [-t=sha1|sha256|sha512|md5] [-c=signature] [-f=]filepath

---

### 2. Command-line arguments

- `-?`, `--help`, `-h`
  Prints out the options.
- `-f`, `--file=VALUE`
  Filename.
- `-t`, `--type`, `--hashtype=VALUE`
  Hashtype  Defaults to `md5`.
- `-c`, `--check=VALUE`
  Optional: check - the signature you want to check. Not case sensitive.

---

### 3. Examples of usage

```sh
# Check md5 for "E:\Саша Неотразима\Sasha-Irresistible.exe" file
SashaChernykh@DESKTOP-0G54NVG E:\Саша Неотразима
$ checksum -f "E:\Саша Неотразима\Sasha-Irresistible.exe"
342B45537C9F472B93A4A0C5997A6F52
# Check sha256
SashaChernykh@DESKTOP-0G54NVG E:\Саша Неотразима
$ checksum -f "E:\Саша Неотразима\Sasha-Irresistible.exe" -t=sha256
F6286F50925C6CBF6CBDC7B9582BFF833D0808C04283DE98062404A359E2ECC4
# Correct 41474147414741474147 sha256 hash or not?
SashaChernykh@DESKTOP-0G54NVG E:\Саша Неотразима
$ checksum -f "E:\Саша Неотразима\Sasha-Irresistible.exe" -t=sha256 -c 41474147414741474147
Error - hashes do not match. Actual value was 'F6286F50925C6CBF6CBDC7B9582BFF833D0808C04283DE98062404A359E2ECC4'
# One more attempt
SashaChernykh@DESKTOP-0G54NVG E:\Саша Неотразима
$ checksum -f "E:\Саша Неотразима\Sasha-Irresistible.exe" -t=sha256 -c F6286F50925C6CBF6CBDC7B9582BFF833D0808C04283DE98062404A359E2ECC4
Hashes match..
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: [winmd5sum](http://www.nullriver.com/products/winmd5sum).
This one's also nice: [sendtoMD5](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/SendTo-MD5.shtml) - right click, send to ..., and it gets you the result.

Answer (score 1):

[**HashTab 3.0**](http://beeblebrox.org/) is a free shell extension that calculates many checksums, including MD5. 
It's integrated as a new tab in the File Properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MD5sums for Windows](http://www.pc-tools.net/win32/md5sums/), a download of only 28 KB ([Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) might be overkill if all you want to do is compute MD5 hashes).

The easiest way to use it is to use Explorer to drag and drop files on md5sums.exe to obtain their MD5 hashes.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a built-in utility, but its a very good option

http://checksumcompare.sanktuaire.com

You could compare checksum by file and/or summaries if two folders differ or are identical.

Answer (score 1):

You can try msys2, it is [here](https://www.msys2.org/).

Just type (algorithm)sum. (algorithm) is the hash algorithm you want to use e.g. md5, sha1, sha256 ...

Unlike Cygwin, this tool is portable, you just to download the .zip file and extract in anywhere you want. You can use it by a simple click(msys2.exe).

Hop this tool will help you.

Answer (score 1):

**[OpenHashTab](https://github.com/namazso/OpenHashTab)** is open source, integrates with Explorer, and is actively developed.

It's a good alternative to [HashCheck](https://github.com/gurnec/HashCheck), as that one isn't maintained any more (for over 6 years).

[image: OpenHashTab 3.0 file properties tab]

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have time to check output from `certutil` character by character `<hash size>` number of times, pipe to `find` utility to see if checksum matches:

```
certutil -hashfile ekaf_elbatuc.exe sha256 | find "<checksum>" && echo File ok. || echo Some mole or rat waz hia
```

But then what's the point of getting hash from same server as the file itself?

Tested on Win 10 CMD

Answer (score 0):

This is how I calculate checksums from Explorer using no third-party software.

On Windows 10 (and probably previous versions) follow these steps:

Using explorer, open the "Send To" folder by typing this into the address bar

```
shell:sendto
```

Create a batch file in this folder called something like **Calculate SHA1 and MD5.cmd**

and add this text

```
@echo off
certUtil -hashfile %1 SHA1
certUtil -hashfile %1 MD5
pause
```

You will now be able to calculate SHA1 and MD5 checksums for any file from Explorer, just by right-clicking a file and choosing send to **Calculate SHA1 and MD5.cmd**

Off course, you can change the name of the above file and choose to add other checksums, or even create multiple files each with a different type of hash.

I have another batch file called **Calculate SHA256.cmd**, which I prefer to use independently (you wouldn't want to calculate every type of hash from one batch file as this would take too long for very big files).

[image]

Some more notes

Just to make the output a little less cluttered, I prefer to pipe the output through findstr.

```
certUtil -hashfile %1 SHA256 | findstr ^1
```

The *pause* instruction at the end of the batch file is essential, otherwise the window will disappear immediately.

Answer (score -1):

There are like 100 third-party tools out there. I use MD5Hash. For downloads with sfv files, just use [TeraCopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeraCopy) to verify the hashes.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I have made [a program](http://slorunnerstipsandtricks.blogspot.com/2014/05/file-hash-checker-v11.html) to calculate some hashes from a file. I hope it helps you.

What does this do?
It calculates the [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash, SHA-384 hash, [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) hash and [SHA-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) hash. Well, that's about it :)

Answer (score -2):

For a solution that works on Windows or just about any other environment, use Python.

1. install Python -- a Windows installer is provided on https://www.python.org/downloads/
2. download a tested `cksum` implementation, e.g. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=cKATyGLb -- save the contents of this to say, `c:\cksum.py` or wherever you find convenient

Then to perform a checksum:

```
python c:\cksum.py INPUTFILE
```

Not as fast as a compiled utility, but compatible with Unix `cksum` and runs anywhere.

Answer (score -3):

I like [digestIT](http://www.colonywest.us/digestit), although it seems to be fairly old and maybe not maintained.