# How to check file against a hash on windows 7?

Tags: windows, hashing

How to check downloaded file against its hash (SHA-256 Hash, SHA-1 Hash, MD5 Hash) on windows?

Comment: As mentioned [at this answer](http://superuser.com/a/89243/247195) - HashCheck is free and open source!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HashTab** is the answer!
http://www.implbits.com/HashTab/HashTabWindows.aspx

After installing, right click on a file, MD5 & SHA-1 will be dispayed in **File Hashes** tab.
Amazing :)