# Trying to install kali on virtual box gets:VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

I am attempting to install kali using virtual box here is a picture of my setup:

[image]

I have downloaded the `iso` file from https://www.kali.org/downloads/

However when i attempt to use the `iso file` i get the following message:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of VirtualBox are you using?  Have you confirmed the ISO you downloaded isn't corrupted?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 im using version: Version 5.0.8 r103449 and i assume that the file is not corrupt when its from their offical website?

Comment: Doesn't mean it didn't get corrupted while downloading it, that's why they give you the SHA1Sum hash for each file -- so you can use it to ensure the hash of your download matches, ensuring the file isn't corrupted.  [Check your hashes](http://superuser.com/questions/245775/is-there-a-built-in-checksum-utility-on-windows-7), and/or download the file again. Also, are you using a 64-bit host OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the .iso has a problem.

However, Kali seems to have problems when trying to install onto Virtual Box/VMWare using the straight .iso file.

[Download a VM ISO Here](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vmware-arm-image-download/) and try it again.