# Windows Checksum Utility

Tags: windows-7, checksum, md5

I would like to install WinMD5Free.exe to run checksums - anyone know if it is legitimate?

Many other sites offer it (CNet etc. so it seems ok). I have to check numerous downloads and want to verify them.

Didn't like the Microsoft CMD one I looked at earlier, prefer GUI.

Comment: Recommendations welcome.

Comment: Questions that at simply a request for software recommendations are off-topic for SU.  Having said that, see this question for some ideas: [Is there a built-in checksum utility on Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/245775/is-there-a-built-in-checksum-utility-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 2):

I saw some users that said that their anti-virus software detected a trojan within WinMD5Free.exe, so I wouldn't trust it.

I do recommend, however, another program that I found useful; HashCheck.  It is open-source, so anyone can verify it and compile the program for themselves.  The link for the home page is here: http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/

Answer (score 2):

Denise, a much better alternative would be to install [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).  It is free, one of the best utilities of its kind, and it also does checksums.

Comment: But not MD5 checksums, though. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Not, it doesn't do MD5 checksums.  That has previously been a 7-Zip feature request, but they apparently prefer to focus on the others (like SHA-256) that are a bit more advanced.

Comment: Thanks to all of your comments and help. If there is a place to ask this type of advice please post the line - I looked and looked last night. I stumbled on checkhash in a Stackexchange post via google later on and it is doing a fab job. Not sure I understand the point of not asking this kind of advice when so many random topics are hosted and a general advice is not to be found, so far ;-)

Comment: We are glad to help, but for something of this nature the Stack Exchange [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) area would probably be ideal.