# How to generate MD5 hash value for multiple files in a folder using cmd

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, hashing, checksum

As mentioned in [this page](https://superuser.com/q/245775/354511),
the command:

```
CertUtil -hashfile yourFileName MD5
```

can be used
to obtain the MD5 hash value for a particular file.

How can I find the MD5 hash values for multiple files in a folder using cmd?

Answer (score 17):

I know you asked specifically for cmd, but if you're using Windows 8.1 or higher, consider using Powershell instead:

```
Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 -Path (Get-ChildItem "\\path\to\files\*.*" -Recurse)
```

The Recurse switch is, of course, optional.  You can pipe it to `Export-Csv` to get a list of files and their hashes.

You *can* use this in Windows 7, but you have to upgrade Powershell to version 4 first.

Comment: Piping results to CSV as `| export-csv -Path D:\abc.csv -NoTypeInformation`.

Answer (score 10):

You could use the following script:

```
for %%f in (*) do (
certutil -hashfile "%%f" MD5
)
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the quotes.   I always remember to use them in Unix, but sometimes I forget about Windows.

Answer (score 5):

The standard way to run a command on multiple files in CMD
is the `for` command. 
You can get usage information by typing `for /?`. 
A simple solution for your problem is

```
for %F in (*) do @certutil -hashfile "%F" MD5
```

Here `%F` is a variable. 
You can choose any letter — any *single* letter — for the variable name
(use the same name in both places, of course) —
and note that it is case-sensitive (`%F` is not the same as `%f`). 
If you do this in a script, use double percent signs (e.g., `%%F`).

The quotes around the second appearance of the variable (`"%F"`)
(as suggested by [nullterminatedstring’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1249377/354511#1249390))
are required if any of the filenames contain spaces.

You can put a list of filenames and/or wildcards between the parentheses;
e.g.,

```
for %F in (file1 file2 a* b*) do …
```

`certutil` is somewhat verbose. 
You may want to cut down on the chatter by saying

```
for %F in (*) do @certutil -hashfile "%F" MD5 | find /v "hashfile command completed successfully"
```

(to filter out the `command completed successfully` messages).

Answer (score 1):

I created this scripts for some reason and Hope this script will helps someone too.

```
@echo off

set count=0

set /p ext="File Extension: "
set /p dest="Directory Path:"
set /p hashtype="Hash Algirthm (MD5,Sha1,Sha256,Sha512): "

:: Robocopy

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION


  
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir !dest!\!ext! /a:-d-l-h /b /s') do (
    
    set file=%%a
    for /f "eol=C tokens=* skip=1" %%b in ('certutil -hashfile "!file!" !hashtype!') do (
        
        set /a count += 1

        echo !count! - "%%b" "!file!"
        echo !count! - "%%b" >> %dest%\hashes.log
        echo !count! - "%%b" "!File!" >> %dest%\Files.log
    )
    
)

exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

I calculated the hash of all files on a drive and exported them to a .csv by using this script in PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem C: -Recurse |
    Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 |
    Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\yourname\Documents\Output\hashes.csv -NoTypeInformation
    Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\yourname\Documents\Output\hashes.csv
```

Be sure to have the .csv file created in that location before you run the script. The script won't create the container for you. There's no need to clear the data from the .csv file between runs, it clears itself.

Run this a few times to make sure you get consistent data output. For some reason my first successful .csv output didn't pull all the data. Tested 2-3 more times and got consistent output after that.

You can then Save As your .csv file as an Excel workbook. .csv files open with Excel.

Comment: The term 'Get-FileHash' is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

For the MD5 file, when you are in the folder the command is:

```
md5deep64.exe -r C:\
```

to add an exported file name it is

```
md5deep64.exe -r C:\ > MD5-Whitelist.txt
```

do the same for the SHA file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What do you mean by "MD5 file" and "SHA file"?