# How to generate MD5 Hash value for only specific files in a folder using CMD

Tags: windows-7

How to get MD 5 Hash value for only few specified files out of a folder using Command Prompt

Comment: Get a cmd tool you can use, use it on those specific files?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such tool included with Windows.

Microsoft provides [FCIV](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841290/availability-and-description-of-the-file-checksum-integrity-verifier-u) for download. It is a command line tool and supports MD5. Use the `-add <file | dir>` parameter to specify a single file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already in the other [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1249377/how-to-generate-md5-hash-value-for-multiple-files-in-a-folder-using-cmd) you asked:

```
for %%f in (*) do (  
certutil -hashfile "%%f" MD5  
)
```

Instead of `*` you can use `*.txt` for example for only hashing .txt files.