# Check if the bootable Windows usb Stick is not corrupted

Tags: windows-8, installation-media

I wonder if there is a simple method to check if an installation USB stick is not corrupted. For a DVD there is a simple method of creating an image and checking its chechsum.

I would like to do similar check also for a Windows usb stick using Windows itself, not some third party tools.

Comment: Duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/245775/is-there-a-built-in-checksum-utility-on-windows-7/898377#898377

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a built-in checksum utility on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/245775/is-there-a-built-in-checksum-utility-on-windows-7)