# Is there a way I can compute MD5 or SHA hashes on Windows and Linux without the need for a specific application?

Tags: md5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a built-in method for computing a sha1 or md5 hash in windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/166233/is-there-a-built-in-method-for-computing-a-sha1-or-md5-hash-in-windows-7)

If I am running Windows 7 or a distribution of Linux how can I compute MD5 or SHA hashes without downloading a specific tool or application that can do so? Are there any tools that come with Windows 7 or distributions of Linux? The Linux distribution of interest would be Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: @afrazier - I am indeed looking for an in-built tool for Windows 7 but am also looking one for Linux.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

md5sum, sha1sum, sha256sum, etc. are all standard in Linux distros.  They're part of the required coreutils package on Debian and Ubuntu, so if you've installed one of those, you already have them.  In other distros you might have to install them, but I don't really see any way around that besides writing them yourself, which I don't think you want to do.

On Windows, I don't know of any native hashing tools.  You'll probably have to install something.  You can install Cygwin, which also includes md5sum and sha*sum in its required coreutils package, or for a free GUI tool there's e.g. [md5summer](http://www.md5summer.org/).

Comment: What about Windows?

Comment: Updated for Windows.

Comment: For various checksum programs and other useful GNU tools for Windows, have a look at gnuwin32 (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Another useful tool (if you have permissinos to install such things in your current environment) for individual files is hashtab (http://implbits.com/HashTab.aspx) which adds the common hash functions to Windows Explorer's file/properties box.

Comment: Hashtab is probably one of the best or Cortez's Checksum.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest Cygwin as above, but OpenSSL tools can perform the hashes. 
See the [OpenSSL](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries) website.