# straightforward simple windows utility to verify md5?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for MD5 utility that integrates to Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/89191/looking-for-md5-utility-that-integrates-to-windows)

I just want to verify md5 checksum of the file. I want to point location of the file and i want utility to automatically find corresponding `md5sum` file and to verify hash.

I've tried this utility http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290/en-us but it can't do that. It uses kind of database and a little bit complicated.

Can you suggest something better?

upd: just found reference to corresponding post [Looking for MD5 utility that integrates to Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/89191/looking-for-md5-utility-that-integrates-to-windows?rq=1)