# Calculate checksum of file from right-click menu?

Tags: windows, right-click, checksum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for MD5 utility that integrates to Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/89191/looking-for-md5-utility-that-integrates-to-windows)

What would be the easiest way to have the checksum of a file shown in a message box using the right click menu on the file, using the following utility to generate the checksum?

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533

Answer (score 7):

There are other tools out there that will do it for you without having to manually set up the right-click association. One that springs to mind is [**HashMyFiles**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/hash_my_files.html).

There are plenty of other tools out there that will do the same thing without having to manually configure it.

Answer (score 1):

I like [digestIT](http://www.colonywest.us/digestit), although it seems to be fairly old and maybe not maintained.